Can one have tooltips with embedded and clickable URLs?
For my Vaadin-based application (Vaadin v24.3.8) I would like to have components with tooltips that give a short explanantion plus include a link into a help-document (i.e. referring to a specific anchor in said help page). I tried to simply add a full URL at the end of the description but that is not renderded like a URL and doesn't make it clickable.
Is that possible somehow? Can one have a clickable URL inside a hover-text? With some limited effort that is...

Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Tooltips don't support interactive content, that feature has been omitted due to accessibility concerns. However the upcoming Vaadin 24.5 will likely include a more generic Popover component that can contain arbitrary content, so you might want to watch out for that.

PopOver is alreadin the latest Vaadin 24.5 alpha release, so it is possible to test it and report issues if you find any.

@cfrick I had simply tried to add a  ... <a href="URL">link text</a> to the text that I set the hovertext with (i.e. view.setTooltipText("... <a href=\"URL\">link text</a>")). But with that the special characters < and > and all text in beteween were shown as quoted and not interpreted as clickable URL. But I guess I'll wait for v24.5 as suggested by Sascha and Tatu.

As an alternative, try addon https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltips4vaadin which allows you to place components inside tooltip

Vaadin 25 (currently in alpha) provides the Popover component which will let you accomplish this. In case you decide to upgrade your Vaadin version, here is an example.
var popover = new Popover();
popover.add(new Anchor("google.com", "Here is a link to google", AnchorTarget.BLANK));

var btn = new Button(VaadinIcon.QUESTION_CIRCLE.create());
popover.setTarget(btn); // position popover relative to our button
btn.addClickListener(e -> popover.open());

add(btn, popover);

